# nginx modifying headers of the url

Tags: nginx, squid

I have configured nginx with servername as t0.t1.t2 and port as 80 and I am doing proxy pass to squid proxy with ipaddress x.x.x.0 and port 3128 and when I am connecting to proxy with servername as t0.t1.t2 and port 80. The request is reaching to squid but it is displaying the page of invalid url.

When I checked I found that browser is sending the correct headers but nginx is modifying the headers and sending to squid. This is the reason squid is displaying invalid url.

Below is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name t0.t1.t2;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://app;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires";
    }

}

upstream app {
    server 127.0.0.1:3128;
}
```

Here are the nginx debug logs:

```
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: accept on 0.0.0.0:80, ready: 1
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: posix_memalign: 00005613FC643650:512 @16
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 event timer add: 3: 60000:1544080301995
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 reusable connection: 1
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 epoll add event: fd:3 op:1 ev:80002001
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: accept() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 http wait request handler
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 malloc: 00005613FC675210:1024
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 recv: fd:3 345 of 1024
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 reusable connection: 0
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 posix_memalign: 00005613FC654FA0:4096 @16
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 http process request line
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 http request line: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 http uri: "/"
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 http args: ""
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 http exten: ""
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 http process request header line
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 http header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 http header: "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5"
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
2018/12/06 07:10:41 [debug] 4007#4007: *1 http header: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
```

As you can see in http uri shows "/".

What I need to change in nginx configuration by which I can configure nginx to directly pass the headers which browser is sending to squid?

Comment: Try using this `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` [Using the Forwarded header](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/)

Comment: I have tried it but it's not working. I'm receiving same error. @GalS

Comment: Ok, and what modifications Nginx does to the headers?

Comment: Which header is wrong? Are you referring to the request line? How do you know what the browser is sending? Have you tested the request using `curl`?

Comment: I have tested using ngrep on port 80 and 3128 and found that browser is sending correct headers and when the headers are reaching to squid they are being modified by nginx. Example - When I request from browser with url "http://remotexs.in" squid is receiving  "/" which you can see in http request line and http uri. @RichardSmith.

Comment: Please refer to the above comment @GalS

Comment: If you enter `remotexs.in` into the browser's address bar, the browser sends an HTTP request with the *request line* as `GET / HTTP/1.1` and the `Host` header as `Host: remotexs.in`. This is correct behaviour - many browsers hide a solitary trailing `/` (but it's still there).

Comment: @RichardSmith But the browser is sending GET http://remotexs.in HTTP/1.1 and when it reaches squid it receives GET / HTTP/1.0 so why is this thing happening ?